# Problems with cordova-plugins and sencha

Tags: cordova, extjs, cordova-plugins

i got a project witch was made with Sencha Cmd 5.0.2.270 and an old cordova version. If i build the project, it ends up successful for both, sencha and cordova. But when running it on devices, no matter if android or ios it seems that cordova does not really work.
The onDeviceReady-Event was fired, but my plugins wont do anything.
For example the splashscreen is not shown and the main issue - my filetransfer does not work.
In my case i try to download some files from a server. The server responds with a 200, but the directory on device was not created and the file not saved. 
The error, i can see in the console:

```
03-18 14:52:22.659: E/FileTransfer(14391): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /zwickauapp/resources/data/poi-images/image-54-3.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-18 14:52:22.659: E/FileTransfer(14391):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)03-18 14:52:22.659: E/FileTransfer(14391):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
03-18 14:52:22.659: E/FileTransfer(14391):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaResourceApi.openOutputStream(CordovaResourceApi.java:317)
03-18 14:52:22.659: E/FileTransfer(14391):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaResourceApi.openOutputStream(CordovaResourceApi.java:298)
03-18 14:52:22.659: E/FileTransfer(14391):     at org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer$4.run(FileTransfer.java:860)
03-18 14:52:22.659: E/FileTransfer(14391):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-18 14:52:22.659: E/FileTransfer(14391):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-18 14:52:22.659: E/FileTransfer(14391):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-18 14:52:22.659: E/FileTransfer(14391): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-18 14:52:22.659: E/FileTransfer(14391):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)03-18 14:52:22.659: E/FileTransfer(14391):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
03-18 14:52:22.659: E/FileTransfer(14391):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
```

Please help. I have no more ideas, how to fix that.

Best regards,
André

Answer (score 0):

Solved: You need to add a cdvfile://localhost/persistent before your os-path. See example of plugin description: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#example-1